# Can't connect two line of vertices together of the same object

Tags: modeling, vertices, retopology, looping

one half was my body retopology, and for the legs I've made a cylinder. After I created it I connected them into one object, in object mode, but now I can't connect the two together by just pressing F in edit mode, they both have the same amount of loops and they align, I've tried to do it manually by selecting two vertices from both side, as seen on the picture, but in smooth and subdividon on, a black line is visible, any tips why this happens?

[image]

[image]

Comment: try recalculate normals command

Comment: as Shantanu Aryan says it may be a problem of inverted normals, try to select all and Shift N to recalculate, or maybe check inner faces, or overlapping vertices (in that case select all and press M > Merge by Distance)

Comment: You could select both loops in edge select mode and select "Bridge Edge Loops" command (available by right clicking or in Edge menu). If you still get that shading issues, try to do the actions mentioned in previous comments.

Comment: turns the problem was that I for got to delete the face at the top of the cylinder ><. I just had it in hidden wire mode all the time and didn't notice it, thank your time tho.